# Adobe Flex OpenWithDefaultApplication Movie

Tags: file, apache-flex, adobe

I am working on an Adobe Air application that I would like to be able to launch a movie using the default application.  The code I am trying is:

```
                var file:File = new File;
//currentMovie.ConfiguredPath = 'D:\\Movies\\TestMovie.avi'; 
                file.nativePath = currentMovie.ConfiguredPath;                  
                file.openWithDefaultApplication();
```

I have also tried this:

```
//currentMovie.ConfiguredPath = file://D:/Movies/TestMovie.avi'
                navigateToURL(newURLRequest(currentMovie.ConfiguredPath));
```

The first option does nothing.  No application opens, no errors, nothing.  The second option worked but it launches a separate window, downloads the file to the local user's download directory then opens the file (as long as you click "Open").  This is not exactly the behavior that I was hoping for.

Comment: What you describe using the second option is exactly what I would expect to happen.  Maybe we have different versions of what "launch a movie using the default application." means.  What type of movie are you trying to launch?  How do you expect a client machine to play a server file without downloading it?

Comment: Yes, I expected the same from option 2 as well.  The movie is a .avi (as shown in the comment above).  The video file is local to the machine that the application will be running on.  So I am hoping to just launch the default application associated with avi on my machine (VLC Player).  I may have made an assumption that is what the openWithDefaultApplication would do.